# USB latency: shorter (than 125us) USB microframes possible?

Tags: usb, driver, microcontroller

Is there any way to implement a USB exchange rate between a Host and a device that has a lower induced latency than with the 125us microframes? For example, an HID device that sends more than 8000 frames per second.

Is this limited by the USB standard? Are there practical limitation preventing us to achieve better USB latencies?

Edit: as per commenter's request, here is specific information from the USB 3.2 spec rev1.1 section 4.3.1:

> USB 2.0 transmits SOF/µSOF at fixed 1 ms/125 μs intervals, with very tight duration and jitter specifications.  Enhanced SuperSpeed links have a similar mechanism called an Isochronous Timestamp Packet (ITP) that is transmitted by a host.  The USB host may send an Isochronous Timestamp Packet (ITP) within a relaxed timing window from a bus interval boundary.  USB 3.0 added a mechanism for devices to send a Bus Interval Adjustment Message that is used by the host to adjust its 125 μs bus interval up to +/−13.333 μs.  A device may change the interval with small finite adjustments.

Whether this ~10% adjustment is meant for clock matching or simply there to explicitly accelerate/decelerate the the transmission rate is unclear to me. In any case, this variation is insufficient for my needs.

As for the use case, I ultimately want the device to send its data as soon as it is ready to the host. I don't want the device to wait for the host to ask for it. Any HID device could benefit from this latency improvement.

Comment: Why do you think does a HID benefit from a latency significantly smaller than 125µs? One actor is a human (the first letter of HID), and humans are notoriously slow. What kind of device do you have in mind? -- Anyway, USB was always host-controlled. Even what is called "interrupt" is actually just a polled flag.

Comment: The thing is, latency adds up fast when you consider the whole system; each asynchronous component has a hit on latency. Take a wireless HID device paired with a USB dongle. User input might be polled by the device (first asynchronous component), then it must go through a wireless medium which might allow for periodic TX (TDMA schemes), then the receiver (dongle) must wait for the Host to poll to deliver the data. The Host OS latency is another part. The combination of asynchronous polling components increases latency significantly. I figured that USB would be the easiest portion to eliminate.

Comment: So you seem to have a specific use case in mind. What is it? And how did you analyze that the USB latency is the part of it that is worth to tackle?

Comment: Can't tell the details, but I can say I have control over the other components and there are hard limits. But from what I am understanding, USB might also be limited, at least when sticking to standards. I'd be curious whether that could be worked around with custom drivers.